# Toast notifications in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Toastr notification plugin in my MVC application to display status messages (successful edit, update, delete, etc), and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to put some logic in a Partial view and have it on my Layout or in each individual view where needed.

### Partial

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @if (ViewBag.Success == true) { 
            @:toastr.success("@ViewBag.Message");
        } else if (ViewBag.Success == false) {
            @:toastr.error("@ViewBag.Message");      
        }
    });
</script>
```

### View

```
//Doesn't work
@Html.Partial("_ToastPartial")

//Tried this directly in the view instead of using the partial, didn't work
@if (ViewBag.Success == true) { 
    @:toastr.success("@ViewBag.Message");
} else if (ViewBag.Success == false) {
    @:toastr.error("@ViewBag.Message");  
}
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult SomethingAwesome(MyViewModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.Success = true;
        ViewBag.Message = "Employee successfully added";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This doesn't work. Is it possible to wrap something like this in a partial or does MVC strip out the `<script>` tags? Can I render the partial within a script block on the View?

I even tried to move the code within the script tags directly to the View and then setting the values on the Controller and it seems like nothing is happening.

Any help? Is the ViewBag cleared by the time the view is rendered again? Should I use TempData? Can I move a `Success` and `Message` property into my ViewModel and just pass that into my View like this?

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model) 
{
    //Do something with model.Success 
}
```

### My Solution

I used a couple of answers to come to a final conclusion for this section of my site, and will most likely use the method for the accepted answer in other parts.

I went and added the following to my ViewModel

```
public bool Success { get; set; } 
public string Message { get; set; }
```

I have the Action return the Index view with the ViewModel, after properties have all been set

```
//fetch the updated data and shove into ViewModel here
viewModel.Success = true;
viewModel.Message = "Employee successfully checked in";

return View("Index", viewModel);
```

And then just use the Razor syntax in my View

```
@if (Model.Success) { 
    @:toastr.success("@Model.Message");
} else if (!Model.Success && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Message)) {
    @:toastr.error("@Model.Message");   
}
```

Also as a bonus (although implementation seems sloppy), render the Partial in my document.Ready block

```
@Html.Partial("_ToastPartial", Model)
```

and move the Toastr notification code to the partial

```
@if (Model.Success) { 
    @:toastr.success("@Model.Message");
} else if (!Model.Success && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Message)) {
    @:toastr.error("@Model.Message");   
}
```

Most likely I would set up an interface with the `Message` and `Success` properties and make any ViewModels that will use the partial implement that interface

Comment: First you should add the `type="text/javascript"` to your script tag and you are missing the quotes in your javascript: `@:toastr.success("@ViewBag.Message")`

Comment: Thanks. Changed my code and will update the question. Didn't make it work magically like I thought it would

Comment: What does your browser console look like? Any errors or warnings? You can debug whether your ViewBag has a message by just sticking an `alert('@ViewBag.Message')` into your `ready` function.

Comment: Hrrrm I have a feeling the ViewBag is missing the values after the Index is redirected to. Alerting the `@ViewBag.Message` came up with nothing on every load

Comment: Try putting your javascript in the main view.

Comment: Updated the question to show the Razor + Javascript in my View directly as something I tried. Still hasn't worked.

Comment: Why did you decide to RedirectToAction as opposed to `return View("Index");`?  See below.

Comment: I can do either, no reason not to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your controller is performing a `RedirectToAction`. The ViewBag and ViewData only survives the current request. TempData is the thing to use when you use redirects (and only then):

http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications states this clearly:

> [...] the TempData object works well in one basic scenario:
>
> - Passing data between the current and next HTTP requests

Comment: This definitely works to solve my problem, however I've decided to use a different method and have updated my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Using this nuget package, it was very easy for me to use toastr in mvc.
I'm a bit surprised it's not used more...
https://www.nuget.org/packages/RedWillow.MvcToastrFlash

Answer (score 1):

Try This library [NtoastNotify](https://github.com/nabinked/ntoastnotify/) if you are looking for a implementation on ASP.NET core. (Disclaimer: Author here)

Comment: I've tried to use your library, but I'm using mvc version 1.0.0, and it gives me warning that this library is not compatible with this version, and I need to update mvc, But I couldn't update mvc version. Is there any other workaround??

Comment: @NullPointer This library works with ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Yeah m also talking about ASP.NET Core MVC

Comment: can you show me your .csproj file for the web project?

Comment: if you web app targets netcoreapp1.1 or above then you can use this library. Check this sample .csproj https://github.com/nabinked/NToastNotify/blob/master/sample/NToastNotify.Web/NToastNotify.Web.csproj where this library is being used.